# ExoPlayer / Media3 HLS Live streaming no merge audio and video sources

Tags: android, kotlin, http-live-streaming, exoplayer, android-media3

I have not been able to play HLS streaming properly for a long time. I searched for an answer to this problem, but could not find a similar case anywhere. The problem is that after loading the streaming I have audio or video only but never both together. It selects randomly.

I have tried to fix this in a number of ways:

- Use MergeDatasource from one url (because i have only one url from server) with only different mime type.
- Use Options:

  ```
  setAllowMultipleAdaptiveSelections(true)
  setAllowVideoMixedMimeTypeAdaptiveness(true)
  setAllowAudioMixedMimeTypeAdaptiveness(true)
  ```
- Overriding and selecting one of the tracks

None of the ways helped. It always displayed either video or audio.
I will try to describe the process:

First I download the url for the video:
https://xyz.abc.com/hls-aes/event/1120190/3/0/livepkgr_e208/230622_1008S415_0345_XYZ/280-450-825/pl.m3u8?pcode=c115&uh=3cc49d68fb4c9b05cec31627a8c0f6ef&base=c115-live-geo900-xyz-hls.secure.footprint.net%2fhls-live&etime=20230622203703&grs=g111&key=ABCDEF

In the next step I get a reply with a manifest where the content type is - `application/vnd.apple.mpegurl`:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:30435
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-VERSION:2
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:2
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://abc.xyz.com/hls-aes/key/1120190/3/0/101/key.bin",IV=ABCDEFGH
#EXTINF:2,
Num30435.ts
#EXTINF:2,
Num30436.ts
#EXTINF:2,
Num30437.ts
#EXTINF:2,
Num30438.ts
#EXTINF:2,
Num30439.ts
```

Num30435.ts is then downloaded, where the content type is: video/MP2T.

The logs most strangely get different ones as well.

**FIRST CASE -> When audio only**

```
timeline `[eventTime=0.69, mediaPos=4.00, window=0, period=0, periodCount=1, windowCount=1, reason=SOURCE_UPDATE] period [?] window [10.00, seekable=true, dynamic=true]`

audioEnabled `[eventTime=0.91, mediaPos=4.00, window=0, period=0]`
tracks `[eventTime=0.91, mediaPos=4.00, window=0, period=0]`

group
- [X] Track:0, id=0, mimeType=audio/mp4a-latm, bitrate=280000, channels=1, sample_rate=22050, supported=YES
- [X] Track:1, id=1, mimeType=audio/mp4a-latm, bitrate=450000, channels=1, sample_rate=22050, supported=YES
- [X] Track:2, id=2, mimeType=audio/mp4a-latm, bitrate=825000, channels=1, sample_rate=22050, supported=YES

group
- [X] Track:0, id=null, mimeType=application/id3, supported=YES

Metadata
- HlsTrackMetadataEntry
downstreamFormat `[eventTime=1.12, mediaPos=4.00, window=0, period=0, id=2, mimeType=null, bitrate=825000]`
audioDecoderInitialized `[eventTime=1.34, mediaPos=4.00, window=0, period=0, c2.android.aac.decoder]`
audioInputFormat `[eventTime=1.34, mediaPos=4.00, window=0, period=0, id=2, mimeType=audio/mp4a-latm, bitrate=825000, codecs=mp4a.40.2, channels=1, sample_rate=22050]`
state `[eventTime=1.59, mediaPos=4.00, window=0, period=0, READY]`
isPlaying `[eventTime=1.60, mediaPos=4.00, window=0, period=0, true]`
timeline `[eventTime=3.27, mediaPos=3.55, window=0, period=0, periodCount=1, windowCount=1, reason=SOURCE_UPDATE]`
- period [?]
- window [10.00, seekable=true, dynamic=true]
```

**SECOND CASE -> When video only**

```
videoEnabled `[eventTime=0.53, mediaPos=4.00, window=0, period=0]`
tracks `[eventTime=0.53, mediaPos=4.00, window=0, period=0]`

group
- [X] Track:0, id=0, mimeType=video/avc, bitrate=280000, supported=YES
- [X] Track:1, id=1, mimeType=video/avc, bitrate=450000, supported=YES
- [X] Track:2, id=2, mimeType=video/avc, bitrate=825000, supported=YES

group
- [ ] Track:0, id=1/8219, mimeType=application/cea-608, supported=YES

group
- [X] Track:0, id=null, mimeType=application/id3, supported=YES

Metadata
- HlsTrackMetadataEntry
downstreamFormat `[eventTime=0.71, mediaPos=4.00, window=0, period=0, id=2, mimeType=null, bitrate=825000]`
videoDecoderInitialized `[eventTime=1.07, mediaPos=4.00, window=0, period=0, c2.qti.avc.decoder]`
videoInputFormat `[eventTime=1.08, mediaPos=4.00, window=0, period=0, id=2, mimeType=video/avc, bitrate=825000, codecs=avc1.4D401F, res=1024x576]`
videoSize `[eventTime=1.11, mediaPos=4.00, window=0, period=0, 1024, 576]`
renderedFirstFrame `[eventTime=1.11, mediaPos=4.00, window=0, period=0, Surface(name=null)/@0xda67faf]`
state `[eventTime=1.18, mediaPos=4.00, window=0, period=0, READY]`
isPlaying `[eventTime=1.18, mediaPos=4.00, window=0, period=0, true]`
```

Here is a code:

```
        val trackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector(this@VideoPlayerActivity).apply {
            setParameters(buildUponParameters()
                .setAllowMultipleAdaptiveSelections(true)
                .setAllowVideoMixedMimeTypeAdaptiveness(true)
                .setAllowAudioMixedMimeTypeAdaptiveness(true)
            )
        }
        player = ExoPlayer.Builder(this@VideoPlayerActivity).apply {
            setSeekBackIncrementMs(durationInMs)
            setSeekForwardIncrementMs(durationInMs)
            setTrackSelector(trackSelector)
        }.build().apply {
            playerExo.player = this
            addAnalyticsListener(EventLogger())
            addListener(playerListener)
            playWhenReady = isPlayerPlaying
            seekTo(currentWindow, playbackPosition)
            stream?.let {
                val mediaDataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory = DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory().apply {
                    setUserAgent(
                        Util.getUserAgent(
                            this@VideoPlayerActivity,
                            "MY_APP_NAME"
                        )
                    )
                    val bandwidthMeter = DefaultBandwidthMeter.Builder(this@VideoPlayerActivity)
                        .setResetOnNetworkTypeChange(false)
                        .build()
                    setTransferListener(bandwidthMeter)
                }
                val hlsOtherExtractorFactory: HlsExtractorFactory = DefaultHlsExtractorFactory(
                    DefaultTsPayloadReaderFactory.FLAG_ALLOW_NON_IDR_KEYFRAMES, true
                )

                val mediaSource: MediaSource = HlsMediaSource.Factory(mediaDataSourceFactory)
                    .setAllowChunklessPreparation(false)
                    .setExtractorFactory(hlsOtherExtractorFactory)
                    .createMediaSource(
                        MediaItem.Builder()
                            .setUri(it)
                            .setMimeType(MimeTypes.APPLICATION_M3U8)
                            //.setMimeType(MimeTypes.VIDEO_MP2T)
                            .build()
                    )

                setMediaSource(mediaSource)
                prepare()
            }
        }
    }
```

Dependencies: I used dependencies for ExoPlayer in version 2.18.7 and on media3 1.0.2. For each type the same error occurs.

This problem does not occur on the old system player using the VideoView.class. Streaming looks fine.

Tested on:

- Huawei P9,
- One Plus 10T
- Samsung M12 Galaxy

I would be grateful for any help!